# Kali Linux lost Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, kali-linux, virtualbox, ethernet

My VirtualBox Kali suddenly lost wired connection.

this is what service network-manager status shows

```
NetworkManager[521]: <warn>  [1587842655.4122] ndisc[0x5568bd5c0200,"eth0"]: failure sending router solicitation: Operation not permitted (1)
```

and that's what i see when trying to ping 8.8.8.8 for example

```
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

when i ping my local hosts - it's alright

what should i check or config?

Comment: are you saying that linux had connectivity, and then lost connectivity without you doing anything?

Comment: There was a similar problem when I installed Toroxy a few days ago. But it was resolved by removing Toroxy and for a while everything was ok. This time I did not do anything

Comment: looks like you have firewall rules preventing both IPv4 and IPv6 ICMP. A DROP in the output path is transmitted as an error to the application (it's not just silently dropped).

Comment: You were absolutely right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It didn’t ping becsuse u need to have the sudo privileges. I don’t know u were using an account that is added to the sudo group if not you should add, or if you are type in sudo -s and enter your password and try to ping it should work.
When it was said failure sending router solicitation operation not permitted it means that you are not signed in as sudo and you don’t have the permissions so do as i said up and it should work.